# Can Kurapika identify the owner of a set of scarlet eyes?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In a few scenes Kurapika comes in contact with the scarlet eyes of his brethren.

I always wondered, if he can identify which pair of eyes belonged to which former Kurta member. Maybe through Nen or just because they mean so much in their culture, that he can naturally tell by having lived with them, when they were alive.

Was that ever addressed in the manga/anime/ or any filler?

Comment: I would guess that he is incapable of distinguishing his brethren based of their "leftover eyes". Once a person dies, their Nen disappears so Kraprika wont be able to use even Nen to tell those eyes apart. Except maybe some eyes are distinguishable based of past scars or appearance

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Nen doesn't necessarily disappear after death, especially, if it wasn't a natural one, but I doubt any Kurta warrior was on that level. Seems like they were a peaceful bunch (if I recall correctly).